# How do you build conditional logic and user options in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Having been happy with ClickOnce for a long time, I've been thrust into the weird and wacky world of windows installers. It appears to be a world very short on documentation, unless I don't know what I'm searching for.

I'm aware there's lots of options for building an installer, including Visual Studio setup projects and WiX. Given that I'm looking at a fairly complex scenario, I suspect I'll be going with the latter. What I'm struggling with is doing something like this:

[image]

Two things to note about this.

First, it already knows what versions of SQL Server I've got installed. Second, the user can select which options to install and which to skip.

I don't know if there's a particular label for these functions that will help me search for them. But I can't find any details on how to start building this sort of logic into an installer, preferably with WiX.

Can anyone get me started?

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky I was just about to - been off the site over the weekend. It's a little rude to hassle people: give them a bit of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This installer UI is WixUI_FeatureTree and it selected by [UI reference](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html).

Each line in the UI is a feature.

Each feature can be nested under other feature.

The name of the feature is a property that is set by [searching the registry](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/read_a_registry_entry.html).

To choose if the feature should be enable, expanded etc. check the [Feature Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/feature.html).

Hope it will get you started...